# Cat blocking when piping output from /usr/bin/gssproxy (`timeout -k 1 1 /usr/bin/gssproxy | cat` does not terminate)

Tags: pipe, timeout

I use `gssproxy` under Arch Linux, in particular

```
Name            : gssproxy
Version         : 0.8.0-1
```

I encountered the following behavior: When trying to pipe the output of 
`/usr/bin/gssproxy`
like so

`/usr/bin/gssproxy | cat`

it blocks. 
However, when I just run this command:
`/usr/bin/gssproxy` it does not block, but creates another process in the background

`root     13720  0.0  0.0  59732   584 ?        Ssl  11:44   0:00 /usr/bin/gssproxy`

and exists.

I acknowledge that there is probably no point in piping the output of `gssproxy`, but nevertheless I am still wondering why this behavior occurs? In particular, what causes `cat` to block?

**EDIT:**

By blocking, I mean that the following command:

`timeout -k 1 1 /usr/bin/gssproxy | cat`,

does not terminate, while

`timeout -k 1 1 /usr/bin/gssproxy`

terminates immediately. Both command spawn `gssproxy` process in the background. I am wondering why the first command 
does not terminate after 1 second as I would expect?

Comment: How do you see that it's blocked? `gssproxy` is a daemon program. I would not be surprised if it simple tests to see whether it's standard output is connected to a terminal or not, and if it's not it may simply decide to not output anything (because it thinks it's running as it should be running, in the background). If it's connected to a terminal, it obviously re-executes itself in the background.

Comment: It might be similar to this: `setsid sleep 5` doesn't block (and forks sleep), `setsid sleep 5 | cat` blocks for the duration of sleep.

Comment: I observed the following situation:
```[root@d48293f221d9]# timeout -k 1 1 /usr/bin/gssproxy | cat
^C
```
```[root@d48293f221d9]# ps aux | grep gssproxy
root     24131  0.0  0.0  59732   588 ?        Ssl  07:44   0:00 /usr/bin/gssproxy
```
where `timeout` does not cause a termination after 1 second, as I would expect. Would you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

As @Kusalananda, mentions `gssproxy` runs as a daemon, the parent process probably wait's untill it's child exits.

Here's a short shell script which emulates the same situation.

```
$ cat t1
#!/bin/bash
sleep 10 &

$ date; ./t1 | cat ; date
Sun Apr  7 10:59:02 BST 2019
Sun Apr  7 10:59:12 BST 2019
```

The date commands are there purely to show that after the subprocess exists (10 seconds) cat terminates

Comment: Thanks! But why is it that `timeout -k 1 1 /usr/bin/gssproxy | cat` does not cause the `gssproxy` process to exit?